# Hola, tengo un problema con mi chat de PHP, cuando quiero subir mi scroll para ver los mensajes anteriores , el scroll se baja automaticamente

Tags: javascript

En las siguientes lineas es done cargo los mensajes anteriores

```
        var loadOldMessages = function(){
            $.ajax({type:"POST", url: "conversation.php"}).done(function( info ){
                $("#conversation").html( info );
                $("#conversation p:last-child").css({"background-color":"lightgreen"});
                var altura = $("#conversation").prop("scrollHeight");
                $("#conversation").scrollTop(altura);
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

se baja inmediatamente por esta linea:

```
$("#conversation").scrollTop(altura);
```

Simplemente no la pongas, es mas nisiquiera requieres calcular esto:

```
var altura = $("#conversation").prop("scrollHeight");
```

Puesto que la idea no es llegar al final del scroll una vez te encuentres arriba.

Comment: Riven pero si le quito esa línea el scroll se queda arriba y la idea es que esté al final para ver los ultimos mensajes enviados

Comment: No entiendo, la idea no es evitar que se vaya al final del scroll?, si se baja hasta al final es porque seguro la función loadOldMessages esta ligada directamente con un evento scroll, el cual se ejecuta para ambas direcciones (ir hacia arriba o ir hacia abajo), en ese caso solo debes comprobar en que dirección se esta haciendo scroll, para en base a ello hacer scroll hacia abajo o no.

Comment: Cuando chateas en facebook o cualquier red social, el scroll se baja hasta el ultimo mensaje. Eso si lo tengo, el problema es que cuando subo el scroll para ver los mensajes anteriores, el scroll se baja al final automaticamente sin dejarme leer los mensajes antiguos